# Array formula and missing rows

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the array formula in a google spreadsheet to automatically insert a row number in column A6:A37 when information is entered in column B6:B37.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT($B6:$B37),IF(ROW($A6:$A37)=6,"#",ROW($A$6:$A37)-6),""))
```

When I enter text in column B7 or below a number appears in Column A corresponding row, exactly as it should.

However the number appears as the number of that row starting from A7 as 1, if I miss a row I would like the number to carry on from the previously entered row number even if that was 1 in B7 and I am now entering text in B12 I would like it to be 2.  If I then added information in B8 how could I get it to auto update to 2 in B8 and 3 in B12 if that is at all possible?

Comment: Is this for Excel? Google Sheets? LibreOffice Calc? Please [edit] your question and add an appropriate tag so we know what tool you're using.

Comment: @Chris Changed and edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

A1:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(B1:B6,(FILTER($B$1:$B$6,B1:B6<>"")),0)))
```

A more accurate version to account for similar values:

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(B1:B6&ROW(B1:B6),(FILTER($B$1:$B$6&ROW(B1:B6),B1:B6<>"")),0)))
```

Comment: Thanks but it is only adding the number 1 in column A it needs to count up each line.So A2 would be 1, A3 would be 2 etc.  But if I skipped a line and entered in A5 then want it to be 3 not 4 which it wold be with the current array formula..  I hope that is clearer.

Comment: Yes. That's what my formula does. You put the formula in A1 .. Write something in B1, then something in B2, You'll get 2 in A2. You skip B3 and write in B4.. then A4 will be 3.

Comment: Based on your comment getting all 1s, I'm guessing B1:B6 contain the same value.... That'll be the only reason, Why you'd get all `1`s. See my edit.

Comment: Perfect thank you.  Yes the column has a drop down of only a set amount of choices some of which would be repeated, sorry for not mentioning that earlier.  marked as answered.

Comment: I'm not getting you. Do you have a problem implementing my formula? Do you just want a extra `#` instead of 1 and 1 instead of 2 and so on? If so, Where do you get struck?

Comment: Although working and marked as answered I am after a bit of refinement if possible, I would like the formula to be in box A6 and there is a column header in B6, so text, I would like then it to show the # sign in box A6 and count the numbers down only if there is text in the column range B7:B37 I have adjusted your (working) formula to this =IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(MATCH($B7:$B37&ROW(B7)='text',"#",(FILTER($B$7:$B$37&ROW(B7)-6,B7:B37<>""(,0))))))) to combine both (again working) formulas to a now not working one.  Can you see the error of my ways and maybe see me clear, thanks.

Comment: I don't quite see the point. Why can't you just type in "#" in A6 and enter only my formula in A7? Why do you want combine new wine and old wine?  Although, For the sake of performance, I do not agree using formula to do this, Try this in A6:  
      `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MATCH(B6:B36&ROW(B6:B36),(FILTER($B$7:$B$36&ROW(B7:B36),B7:B36<>"")),0),IF(ROW(B6:B36)=6,"#","")))`

Comment: Thank you, the main reason is that if anyone inadvertently types anything in A7 (we have been using these sheets for 8 years now and old habits die hard!) then it would delete the formula rendering it all as not working.  Again many thanks.

Comment: @paul Instead, you could protect the ranges. I'm all for lean mean formulas. I hate bloats.

Comment: I have taken your advice and use the original answer and protected the range, I had forgotten about that, I am very sorry for the trouble.